# Соединение строк string в С++ через +, append(), insert() не работает

Tags: c++, строки, c++11, append

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void set_temp_iface(string iface) {
    string temp_iface;
    temp_iface.append(iface);
    cout << temp_iface << endl;
}

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "iface") == 0)
            set_temp_iface(string(argv[2]));

    return 0;
}
```

И результата невидно. В консоли пустая строка. В чем может быть причина? Компилятор g++ 5.4

Comment: Покажите минимальный проверяемый пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: А также укажите, какой компилятор вы используете.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, вот выше код вызова самой функции. Использую g++ 5.4 компилятор

Comment: Это не есть проверяемый код. Покажите готовую к компиляции минимальную программу, воспроизводящую проблему.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, а это?

Comment: Это не соответствует слову "минимальный".

Comment: Выкиньте все ваши объявления и напишите простую программу, где есть простая функция и ее вызов, которые, как вы считаете, не соответствуют ожидаемому поведению.

Comment: А почему в коде после проверки `argv[j]` вдруг делается прямое обращение по фиксированному индексу `argv[3]`???

Comment: @AnT, это член другого класса.

Comment: @Vova Polischuck  Я же ясно написал: "Выкиньте все ваши объявления". Это не есть готовая к компиляции программа. Она не компилируется.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, а теперь?

Comment: @Vova Polischuck  Мне не хочется повторять одну и тоже в энный раз.

Comment: @Vova Polischuck  Напишите    if( argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "iface") == 0)
            set_temp_iface(string(argv[2]));
и после этого сами ее запустите и проверьте результат.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, сейчас код работает. Но из проблемой в проэкте я так и не разобрался

Comment: @Vova Polischuck  И 1) совсем необязательно использовать аргументы командной строки. Просто объявите std::string s( "iface"); И ее используйте. 2) Вставьте заголовки, чтобы была готовая к компиляции программа, чтобы ее можно было бы скопировать один к одному и запустить на своем компьютере.

Comment: @Vova Polischuck Тем не менее вы проделали полезную работу и убедились, что append работает корректно. Теперь расширяйте этот базовый пример постепенно, пока не возникнет проблема.

Comment: У вас не верно построен алгоритм.  string temp_iface; - обьявлена локально, зачем ей делается append - не понятно, т.к. переменная изначально пустая, а за тем выводится на экран arg[2]. этот код можно написать проще. Если вы работаете с char[] то вам подойдёт **strcat** или vsprintf или подобная.